# Аналог setw() в C#

Tags: c#

Требуется вывести таблицу умножения в консоли примерно подобном виде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т. е. так, чтобы все элементы располагались точно друг под другом.
В С++ есть `setw()`, который позволяет настроить ширину вывода строки. Как сделать то же самое на С#?

Код программы без форматированного вывода:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(i*j);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: [Пробовали](https://www.google.pl/search?source=hp&q=setw+c%23&oq=setw)  [гуглить](http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread527047.html)?

Comment: Да, но ничего нужного я не нашел

Comment: Я ж вам [ссылку дал](http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread527047.html)

Answer (score 5):

Используйте форматирование

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0,5}",i*j);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `PadLeft`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
    {
        Console.Write((i * j).ToString().PadLeft(4));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Если строка имеет длину менее 4 символов, то она будет дополнена пробелами слева до этой длины.